# Bitlocker TPM + PIN vs password without TPM

Tags: encryption, hardware, tpm, bitlocker

I keep reading how it's best to use Bitlocker's full disk encryption with a TPM + PIN instead of just a passphrase twithout a TPM but I've been wondering why.

Assuming that a very strong password is used, the only way to penetrate Bitlocker's FDE is by performing a bruteforce attack, which is pretty much impossible with a strong password.

Since Bitlocker setups without PINs have already been [bypassed](https://dolosgroup.io/blog/2021/7/9/from-stolen-laptop-to-inside-the-company-network) in the past, I don't see why there cannot be a similar vulnerability for setups with a PIN. The way I see it, the TPM just adds another attack vector on top of it. I would very much like to hear an expert opinion on this.

Comment: "I keep reading ..." can you provide a reference?

Comment: Short answer: the TPM does far more than just accept a PIN or a password. It makes other checks to ensure that the system is intact before booting. Without the TPM, it becomes possible to bruteforce offline by removing the media. Whether or not a "strong password" is equivalent to a TPM in a certain use case is up to your own risk assessment.